# Strongly Types useDynamicCallback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using ag-grid with React and would like to use useDynamicCallback function. However, the given example is a js one and I would like to use it in typescript.

Below is what they have:

```
function useDynamicCallback(callback) {
    const ref = useRef();
    ref.current = callback;
    return useCallback((...args) => ref.current.apply(this, args), []);
}
```

Below is how I added types to escape ts-lint errors:

```
const useDynamicCallback = (callback: any) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    ref.current = callback;
    return useCallback((...args) => (ref as any).current.apply(this, args), []);
};
```

Can someone help me with a strongly typed function so I can get away with any, if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to use `this` in the arrow function because arrow functions establish "this" based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within, just call the callback with the parameter directly. See [call, apply and bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#call_apply_and_bind)

But if you insist to use it, here is the type-safe version:

```
import { useRef, useCallback } from 'react';

type AnyFunction = (...args: any) => any;

function useDynamicCallback(this: ThisParameterType<AnyFunction>, callback: AnyFunction) {
  const ref = useRef<AnyFunction>();
  ref.current = callback;
  return useCallback((...args: Parameters<AnyFunction>) => ref.current?.apply(this, args), []);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMBK6BmAaFDAYQEMAbMgIxIGMBrOAXzhyghDgHIp1aZOA3AFgAUKJgBPMOjgBBAHYSAYsnk0YwCPLgBeOAAoAdMZJQA5qgBccEooCUugHw3FwsSJyr1m7WnQARCXkSEGAaUgpqen0YAAtgKzgAFXjUAAVTEPQYdCgkqXQAHgVlLw0tRwIacipaOmsSlTVy+QcEUTg4Gi1UeB4cXUIsXGLFJu8K-Ts3Tv7DGmQoHnl4PWrIupm4HhhF32IaqLp9IxNzRIyoLJyoVFHS5p9HBx1nOYWl9BWAfkMSMDAZAkMVSBFMFjsBAA2gBdaaiRhAA)

Comment: Thanks. Whats the alternative without “this” keyword?

Comment: @a2441918 `ref.current?.(...args)`

Comment: Instead of .apply(this,args), I just spread args?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function useDynamicCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(callback: T): T {
  const ref = React.useRef(callback);
  ref.current = callback;
  return React.useCallback((...args: unknown[]) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
    return ref.current.apply(null, args);
  }, []) as T;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry mate. This didnt work.